# Continuous injective functions with dense image

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $X$ be the set of continuous, injective functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with dense image; and equip $X$ with the (relative) compact-open topology.  What is known about this space?

In particular, are all such maps [cell-like (cellular)](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/siebappr.pdf)?

Comment: Just looking at what you link, it seems to suggest that if it were cell like such a thing would be a limit of homeomorphisms which obviously can’t happen if the dimensions are different.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Yes sorry, $n$ is replaced with $m$.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: An injective map is cellular if and only if it is bijective.